# How to track searched Keyword on Google for my website

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, web-analytics

I am just want to Track my site referrers using PHP.

If i will search my website on Google then i am not getting Keywords in referrals URL.

Below for example if i will searched **wikipedia**. then this url will my Referrer URL.

Here in below URL `&q=` is blank.

```
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F&ei=9VxbVJekIY6luQTly4KIAg&usg=AFQjCNFoqWBYY9IYRUE6eu9l7l73Wk5wYw&bvm=bv.78677474,d.c2E
```

How to track searched Keyword on Google for my website.

My first preference without Google analytic.

Same [Piwik](http://piwik.org/what-is-piwik/) APi i have used. but [Piwik](http://piwik.org/what-is-piwik/) is also not able to track Keywords.

Comment: this maybe helpful https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en

Comment: You cannot. It's not possible. Keywords are not transmitted for encrypted search queries, and since almost all search queries are encrypted by now you do not get organic keywords anymore. This is not a matter of the technology on the receiving end - the information is not send, so it cannot be extracted.

Comment: @EikePierstorff ok i understand.. so how could i do this if i need..

Answer (score 1):

2011 Google switched to https (first just for user logged in to a google-account - now for all). It´s called the Safe Search Update.
Since then it´s impossible for all webtrackingsystems to get the keywords a user searched for.

There are some Workarounds, that could help you:

1. use the Search Console (here you get a idea about your rankings but
   not about conversion or behavioral metrics of each keyword)
2. for some Webanalytics-Tools you find workarounds to get the keyword
   for example here:
   https://blog.kissmetrics.com/unlock-keyword-not-provided/
3. There are some tools on the market that provide you the keywords
   (but I think only in Google Analytics) for example:
   https://keyword-hero.com